# Unable to set the property of the class range FormulaArray in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, csv

```
    Sub Parse()


        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Users\karthic.rangaraj\Desktop\4401.csv"

         ' Parse it using comma and semicolon as delimiters
        Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:= _
        Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 2))


        Range("B:B,D:D").Delete
         'Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "Application_ID"

         Dim lLR As Long
    Dim vArray As Variant
    Dim sString As String
     '*****************************************************************************************
     'Add as many items you like to this array
     '*****************************************************************************************
    vArray = Array("Windows XP", "Adobe", "IBM", "VLC", "PDFCreator", "Sonic", "Office", "Sigamtel", "Printer")
    For i = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
        sString = sString & Chr(34) & vArray(i) & Chr(34) & ","
    Next i
     '*****************************************************************************************
     'This is the final array string that we pass to array formula
     '*****************************************************************************************
    sString = "{" & Left(sString, Len(sString) - 1) & "}"
    lLR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("D2").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(" & sString & ",1,MATCH(1,--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & sString & ",$C2,1)),0))"


    Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & lLR)
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\karthic.rangaraj\Desktop\4401.xls", FileFormat:=56
' 52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = xlsm (workbook with macro's in 2007)

    End Sub
```

I can save this single file as .xls file using this code

```
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\karthic.rangaraj\Desktop\4401.xls", FileFormat:=56
    ' 52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = xlsm (workbook with macro's in 2007)
```

Here are my questions:

1. How can i access a bunch of CSV files in a folder `C:\Users\karthic.rangaraj\Desktop\CSVFiles`
     & Save it as a XLS file in the same folder after the process is done in the same file names using VBA?
2. I have a problem in the array:

Code:

```
vArray = Array("Windows XP", "Adobe", "IBM", "VLC", ".Net Framework", "Office", "Java", "Windows Media", "J2SE", "MSXML")
        For i = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
            sString = sString & Chr(34) & vArray(i) & Chr(34) & ","
        Next i

sString = "{" & Left(sString, Len(sString) - 1) & "}"
lLR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("D2").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(" & sString & ",1,MATCH(1,--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & sString & ",$C2,1)),0))"
Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & lLR)
```

if enter more than 10 items (let's say 14) i'm getting this error message:

```
Unable to set the property of the class range FormulaArray
```

What's wrong with the array formula here?

Comment: error message is in this line exactly:`Range("D2").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(" & sString & ",1,MATCH(1,--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & sString & ",$C2,1)),0))"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So whats wrong with this simpler formula?

```
vArray = Array("Windows XP", "Adobe", "IBM", "VLC", ".Net Framework", "Office", "Java", "Windows Media", "J2SE", "MSXML")
        For i = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
            sString = sString & Chr(34) & vArray(i) & Chr(34) & ","
        Next i

sString = "{" & Left(sString, Len(sString) - 1) & "}"
lLR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("D2").Formula = "=HLOOKUP($C2," & sString & ",1,FALSE)"
Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & lLR)
```

**EDIT:**

OK Now I understand what you are trying to do: try this code

```
Sub Joe()
vArray = Array("Windows XP", "Adobe", "IBM", "VLC", ".Net Framework", "Office", "Java", "Windows Media", "J2SE", "MSXML")
        For i = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
            sstring = sstring & Chr(34) & vArray(i) & Chr(34) & ","
        Next i
sstring = "{" & Left(sstring, Len(sstring) - 1) & "}"
lLR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("E2").Formula = "=InList($C2," & sstring & ")"
Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & lLR)
End Sub
Function InList(theCell As Range, theList As Variant)
    Dim j As Long
    Dim str As String
    InList = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    str = UCase(Trim(CStr(theCell)))
    For j = LBound(theList) To UBound(theList)
        If str Like UCase("*" & theList(j) & "*") Then
            InList = theList(j)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
End Function
```

Comment: it didn't even match a single item to col D from col C.

Comment: I'm sorry, even this formula not even matching a single array item. As you said in the beginning an array can create is 255 characters then iDevlop said i need to split the arrays`ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyList",  RefersTo:=Array(Array("Windows XP", "Adobe", "IBM"))`then add in my array formula. I'm not sure how can I do this :(! Thank you for your support.

Comment: it works for me on your test data with the list in column C and puts the matches in column E

Comment: could you post the full code 'cause when i tried in my system it's not working & it copied no name in Col E. Thank u.

Comment: I already posted the full code - starting with Sub Joe and ending with End Function. If your list of data is in column C run the Sub Joe and it will produce the matches in Column E

Comment: I have deleted my original code from `Dim lLR As Long`till `Range("D2").FormulaArray` then I called your code  `Call Joe` `End`. Finally in Col E it copied like this `#NOM?` (Name)

Comment: Probably either you have not copied the Function InList code into your module or your code is not in a General Module. I suggest you add a new module, copy ALL my code (from Sub Joe to End Function) into the new module and then run the Sub Joe.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum length of arrayformula that VBA can create is 255 characters

Comment: What is your array formula supposed to be doing that can't be done with a simple MATCH or VLOOKUP?

Comment: :`vArray = Array("Windows XP", "Adobe", "IBM", "VLC", ".Net Framework", "Office", "Java", "Windows Media", "J2SE", "MSXML")`this the array. It has 10 items if i enter 11nth item it display the error message as I mentioned in the question. This array items look for match text in `Col C`  & put the matched item in `Col D`

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Charles Williams answer, you could put the software list array in a (optionally hidden) "named constant" using Define Names, and use that named array in your formula to make it shorter.

```
 ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyList", _
                     RefersTo:=Array(Array("Windows XP", "Adobe", "IBM")
```

...

```
Range("D2").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(MyList,1,...
```

That would make the lenght of your formula independent from the number of items.

Comment: Error in this line : `Range("D2").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(MyList,1," & sString & ",1,MATCH(1,--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & sString & ",$C2,1)),0))"`